# Trying to have go to home activity, if another app starts running and then my app starts running

Tags: android

I'm trying to write code so if my app is running, then some one exits and brings up a activity from another app, it will start from the home (first) activity when the user returns to it.

The strange thing is that my code is producing a blank black screen when the user exits my apps activity and tries to return to it.

I tried to call finish in the onRestart.

My code:

```
public void onRestart()
{
   super.onRestart();
   finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` in your manifest in the `<activity ...>` section for your root activity. Remove your onRestart code.